# Delete contents of blob field from one record

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7

I am using Absolute database components (database, tables, datasource), I need to delete the contents of one blob field in one record. I have tried everything I know how to do, but I don't seem to be able to get the job done.

Is there a way to delete the contents of one field during run time?

Answer (score 0):

```
With YourTableHere do
Begin
   edit;
   fieldbyname('YourFieldHere').clear;
   post;
end
```

Make sure that the record you wish to delete the Blob Field from, has focus.
Great if you use a datagrid.

Comment: I don't think that the "focus" part is relevant (nor the "datagrid"). the record simply needs to be the current/active record. also executing an UPDATE SQL with YourFieldHere=NULL will do the job.

Comment: Delphi doesn't have a `DataGrid`. Did you perhaps mean `TDBGrid`? There's no "focus" for a database table row. Also, UGH to the answer containing a `with` statement. (Not downvoting your answer, but there are a lot of things not quite correct that you might want to edit and fix.)